# Removing an array item with "constraints"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a routine to remove a customer and its address, but only if the address isn't attached to another customer on the customer object list.

Here is my code:

// my data

```
var allData = [
   { type: "store", data: { store_id: 297, name: "Scotiabank - Main Branch", 
address_id: 1023 } },
   { type: "store", data: { store_id: 614, name: "Scotiabank - Hamilton", 
address_id: 1984 } },
   { type: "store", data: { store_id: 193, name: "Scotiabank - Mississauga", 
address_id: 1757 } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 26, store_id: 297, first_name: 
"Dave", last_name: "Bennett", email: "dbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, 
add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 59, store_id: 193, first_name: 
"John", last_name: "Stevens", email: "jstevens22@hotmail.com", address_id: 
2473, add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 29, store_id: 614, first_name: 
"Sarah", last_name: "Pym", email: "spym99@hotmail.com", address_id: 1611, 
add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 63, store_id: 297, first_name: 
"Steven", last_name: "Edwards", email: "steven2231@hotmail.com", address_id: 
1836, add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 71, store_id: 614, first_name: 
"Martin", last_name: "Scott", email: "mdog33@gmail.com", address_id: 2727, 
add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 24, store_id: 614, first_name: 
"Jonathan", last_name: "Pym", email: "jjpym@yahoo.ca", address_id: 1611, 
add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 36, store_id: 193, first_name: 
"Kaitlyn", last_name: "Adams", email: "katy38@hotmail.com", address_id: 
5464, add_date: null } },
   { type: "customer", data: { customer_id: 73, store_id: 297, first_name: 
"Melissa", last_name: "Bennett", email: "mbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 
4536, add_date: null } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 1023, address: "2895 Yonge St.", 
city: "Toronto", province: "ON", postal_code: "L4C02G" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 1984, address: "3611 Main St. 
West", city: "Hamilton", province: "ON", postal_code: "R5O8H5" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 1757, address: "1177 Ontario St. 
Unit 8", city: "Mississauga", province: "ON", postal_code: "L9H6B3" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 4536, address: "3945 John St.", 
city: "Ajax", province: "ON", postal_code: "L7M4T9" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 2473, address: "391 Baker St. Apt 
231", city: "Mississauga", province: "ON", postal_code: "M4T8S3" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 1611, address: "183 City Ct.", 
city: "Hamilton", province: "ON", postal_code: "J3T9V2" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 1836, address: "67 Rhymer Ave.", 
city: "Stouffville", province: "ON", postal_code: "L3C8H4" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 2727, address: "287 Brant St. Apt 
4A", city: "Waterdown", province: "ON", postal_code: "R93G3P" } },
   { type: "address", data: { address_id: 5464, address: "11 New St. Apt 
2B", city: "Brampton", province: "ON", postal_code: "L694R7" } },
];
```

// my object

```
var CustomerDB = {
   customers: [],
   addresses: [],
   stores: [],
   insertData: function (allData) {
      for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
         if (allData[i].type == "store") {
            this.addStore(allData[i].data);
         }
         else if (allData[i].type == "customer") {
            this.addCustomer((allData[i].data));
         }
         else if (allData[i].type == "address") {
            this.addAddress((allData[i].data));
         }
      }

   },
```

// Loading data

```
CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
```

This removeCustomerById function works perfecly, except for the removeAddressById:

```
removeCustomerById: function (customer_id) {

      var address_id_remove;
  
      for (var i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {
         if (this.customers[i].customer_id == customer_id) {
            address_id_remove = this.customers[i].address_id;
            this.customers.splice(i, 1);
            this.removeAddressById(address_id_remove);
          }
     
      }
           
   },
```

// removeAddresById code

```
 removeAddressById: function (address_id) {
  
      for (var i = 0; i < this.addresses.length; i++) 
      {
    
         if (this.addresses[i].address_id == address_id) 
         {
        
            if (this.addressExistsInCustomer(address_id))
            {
               console.log("bout to remove an address " + 
this.addresses[i].address_id)
               this.addresses.splice(i, 1);
            }
         }
      }
  
   },
```

//addressExistsInCustomer code

```
    addressExistsInCustomer: function (address_id) {
        return this.customers.some(c => c.address_id == address_id)
   },
```

addressExistsInCustomer never returns true, even though it should. I feel like I'm overlooking something silly and need a set of fresh eyes...

Comment: Please cut down on unnecessary code. Leave only the essential.

Comment: @andremello Way are not using lodash?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {
  return (this.customers[i].address_id == address_id)
}
```

This loop makes the function return always in the first iteration of the loop regardless of whether the value is `true` or `false`.

What you want to do is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {
  if (this.customers[i].address_id == address_id) return true
}
return false
```

This makes sure that the function only returns when (or *as soon as*) the expression evaluates to `true` and will continue to the next iteration if it evaluates to `false`. If the expression did not evaluate to `true` in any iteration, the code after the loop will be executed and the function returns `false`.

Comment: I fixed that and still nothing - never returns true

Comment: Then there's **another** problem with your code. I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is returning at the first iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {
    return (this.customers[i].address_id == address_id)
}   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A good approach is using function `some`

```
addressExistsInCustomer: function (address_id) {
    return this.customers.some(c => c.address_id == address_id)
}
```

This snippet illustrates how function `some` works, basically finds for an object with `address_id` equals to the passed as param.

```js
var customers = [  {    "type": "store",    "data": {      "store_id": 297,      "name": "Scotiabank - Main Branch",      "address_id": 1023    }  },  {    "type": "store",    "data": {      "store_id": 614,      "name": "Scotiabank - Hamilton",      "address_id": 1984    }  },  {    "type": "store",    "data": {      "store_id": 193,      "name": "Scotiabank - Mississauga",      "address_id": 1757    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 26,      "store_id": 297,      "first_name": "Dave",      "last_name": "Bennett",      "email": "dbennett@gmail.com",      "address_id": 4536,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 59,      "store_id": 193,      "first_name": "John",      "last_name": "Stevens",      "email": "jstevens22@hotmail.com",      "address_id": 2473,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 29,      "store_id": 614,      "first_name": "Sarah",      "last_name": "Pym",      "email": "spym99@hotmail.com",      "address_id": 1611,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 63,      "store_id": 297,      "first_name": "Steven",      "last_name": "Edwards",      "email": "steven2231@hotmail.com",      "address_id": 1836,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 71,      "store_id": 614,      "first_name": "Martin",      "last_name": "Scott",      "email": "mdog33@gmail.com",      "address_id": 2727,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 24,      "store_id": 614,      "first_name": "Jonathan",      "last_name": "Pym",      "email": "jjpym@yahoo.ca",      "address_id": 1611,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 36,      "store_id": 193,      "first_name": "Kaitlyn",      "last_name": "Adams",      "email": "katy38@hotmail.com",      "address_id": 5464,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "customer",    "data": {      "customer_id": 73,      "store_id": 297,      "first_name": "Melissa",      "last_name": "Bennett",      "email": "mbennett@gmail.com",      "address_id": 4536,      "add_date": null    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 1023,      "address": "2895 Yonge St.",      "city": "Toronto",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "L4C02G"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 1984,      "address": "3611 Main St. West",      "city": "Hamilton",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "R5O8H5"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 1757,      "address": "1177 Ontario St. Unit 8",      "city": "Mississauga",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "L9H6B3"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 4536,      "address": "3945 John St.",      "city": "Ajax",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "L7M4T9"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 2473,      "address": "391 Baker St. Apt 231",      "city": "Mississauga",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "M4T8S3"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 1611,      "address": "183 City Ct.",      "city": "Hamilton",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "J3T9V2"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 1836,      "address": "67 Rhymer Ave.",      "city": "Stouffville",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "L3C8H4"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 2727,      "address": "287 Brant St. Apt 4A",      "city": "Waterdown",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "R93G3P"    }  },  {    "type": "address",    "data": {      "address_id": 5464,      "address": "11 New St. Apt 2B",      "city": "Brampton",      "province": "ON",      "postal_code": "L694R7"    }  }];

var addressExistsInCustomer = (address_id) => {
  return this.customers.some(c => c.data.address_id === address_id);
}

console.log(addressExistsInCustomer(1023));
console.log(addressExistsInCustomer(999900));
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Using `.some` is quite elegant, but since it does basically the same as my answer it doesn't solve the problem according to OP.

Comment: yea i was about to say that @NiklasHigi caught that error and I tried to fix it but it didn't work. I changed my code to use .some just in case, and didn't work either.

Comment: @andremello can you share the whole code of `CustomerDB`?

Comment: @Ele sorry I'm fairly new to the site, what's the best way to do this? I don't want to flood the post

Comment: I just copied the entire code into the Chrome console and played around with it and the function seems to work as expected. Calling it with an address ID that's actually assigned to a customer inside `allData` returns `true`, calling it with any other number returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Technicaly this address should be removed then and it wasn't.... { type: "address", data: { address_id: 2727, address: "287 Brant St. Apt 4A", city: "Waterdown", province: "ON", postal_code: "R93G3P" } },